# Tips for communicating with non programmers

Tags: communication

I'm a one man developer PHP/MySQL developer.  The contents of our database come an excel file produced by a group on non programmers.  They are smart people, but often don't see how small changes in excel file can totally make the logic in my PHP codes meaningless.  Does anyone have tips for communicating with non-programmers in these types of scenarios?

Comment: Be honest, clear, concise, and friendly.

Comment: As a programmer, I really feel that communicating with non-programmers is a big part of my job and I do feel that this question is programming related.

Comment: @Closers - Sincerely for clearification - does stackoverflow only want programming questions and not those involving other aspects of the software lifecycle (requirements, estimating, design, testing, maintenence, training)?  Requirements gathering and training involves communicating with non programmers.

Comment: I voted for reopen. It looks appropriate for SO to me

Comment: Are the changes that cause problems due to incorrect data model assumptions in the code?

Comment: Communication issues are not programming related - every other dept (marketing, HR, analysis, etc) can all say that whomever they are talking to doesn't seem to grasp a key issue.  It's all about knowing your audience, and catering to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I explain things like this to non-programmers, I usually tell them that a computer can't figure out anything that I don't tell it SPECIFICALLY.  Ask them how you would write a program to go get gas for the car.  When they answer, explain the details they've surely missed (like how to get the keys out of their pocket, and how to take steps, etc.).

Answer (score 6):

Provide them with a template which you require them to use.  If they get in the habit of asking before making any change, then maybe they'll either stop making changes, or figure out what kinds of things are okay and which are not.

Answer (score 5):

Use metaphors and real-world analogies in terms of things they can understand.

I was explaining to my aunt how the hard disk filling up can make a computer slow:

"Just imagine that you're in a small room and it gets completely filled up. Now to put anything new in, you have to move one pile out of the way, then another, just to get to the shelf by the wall. It gets slower and slower to put anything else in".

or, since they use Excel spreadsheets, you could say

"Imagine you have spreadsheet macros to calculate the costs for all kinds of things that we buy, and to automatically calculate the tax as well. Suppose the government changes the tax on everything by 1% .. it's just a small change, but now you have to change every one of your spreadsheets".

Answer (score 4):

Just a tip: When I have to describe general/logistical topics, I try to relate the programming phenomenon with an analogy/metaphor using things familiar to them.

> Try to relate things that they encounter in their occupation to programming operations.

Comment: I never use analogies. They're like a using a monkey to drive a car to get fruit, when what you wanted was a pineapple juice.

Comment: I agree. I've used analogies before and they grossly oversimplify most programs and it usually causes a lot more confusion when something happens outside the usefulness of the analogy.

Comment: Maybe you need metaphors instead, sprinkled with alliteration.

Comment: +1 silky - it took me a day but I just got it :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using password protection and macros to dissallow the changes that cause the problems?